# React Router: need

Tags: reactjs, router

I have this code I have been trying to get to work. Cannot figure out whats wrong with it! There are no errors and I have tried several ways of importing/exporting, and changing the functions to const.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./Home";
import { Contact } from "./Contact";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/contact">
              <Contact />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

Then I have two separate functions 

    import React from "react";

export function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Whats up!</h2>
      <p>This is sample text. </p>
    </div>
  );
}
    import React from "react";

export function Contact() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Contact page!</h2>
      <p>This is different text. </p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Contact;
```

Comment: If you temporarily remove the `react-router` parts of your code, and try just rendering `Home` and `Contact` side-by-side in the `App` component, does it display properly? In short, have you ruled out that the problem is something other than `react-router`?

Comment: Yes! it displays properly, I guess could it be an issue with switch? The above code actually displays whatever is in the first Route no matter the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment - "The above code actually displays whatever is in the first Route no matter the url", the issue is that you're not providing the `Route` components with an `exact` prop of `true`.

`Switch` will render the first matching `Route` and skip all the other ones. Since `/` "matches" all routes, you're only seeing the `Home` component.